# QGIS Raster Merge Outputs Mysterious Bands

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I am using the Raster>Miscellaneous>Merge tool in QGIS to merge two different GeoTiff(s) into one layer. They are two different agricultural fields. When I merge them, it seems that the rgba bands are not retaining their values. Is there something I am missing? I understand the black is just the no data value I set. Not worried about that. I need the third image to have the first and second image with that rgba structure.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]